# Javascript progres bar on addEventListener

Tags: javascript, progress-bar, addeventlistener

i'm trying to get a progress bar while a javascript code is executed. This code is sending image data to a saving.php file. I saw that on a local server it's quite fast but on the online server it's slower (more or less 10 seconds) and the page freeze, but i won't to show a progress bar for the user so that he/she knows something is going on while he's waiting.
Here is the Javascript:

```
savingButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var lang = document.getElementById("lang").value;
    var name = document.getElementById("row1").value;
    var dirname = document.getElementById("directory").value;
    var imageURL = c.toDataURL("image/png");
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("POST", 'saving.php?dir='+dirname, false);
    ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/upload');
    ajax.send(imageURL);
    window.location.assign("output.php?dir="+dirname+"&name="+name+"&lang="+lang);
},false);
```

Thanks to all in advance!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress -- if you encounter problems with this, feel free to ask again. :)

Comment: Thank you very much, i'll give it a try and let you know! Thanks again